How to use scala function to match error message with a Regex pattern
This function needs to take a given error message, match it to a Regex pattern and return either a prescribed error message or  a None
I built the below function where Regex values are preset and the error message = exMess
I know that regex pattern matches if I use exReg.findFirstIn(exMess), but otherwise the match statement only returns None and does not return any of the matching  error messages
Intellij is not showing any error that would explain what is wrong
How do I need to handle the Match statement so that it can take the error message, match it with the specific Regex pattern and return a string or None
where exMess = "parseR.TokenException: at line 1"
 

def exceptionBasicRow(exMess: String): Option[String] = {
    val exReg: Regex = ("parser[R,I,N].TokenException: at line 1").r
    val exReg2: Regex = ("parser[R,I,N].ParseException: at line 1").r
    val exReg3: Regex = ("parser[R,I,N].ParseException: at line 1").r


    val error: Option[String] = exMess match {
      case exReg(_) =>
        Option(
          "There is a exReg error")
      case exReg2(_) =>
        Option(
          "There is a exReg2 error")
      case exReg3(_) =>
        Option(
          "There is a exReg3 error")
      case _ => None
    }
    error
 }

I also tried the following syntax, but findFirstIn does not seem accessible from inside the Match statement (colored red)
exMess match{
   case exReg.findFirstIn(exMess)  => print("Error Message")
}


At first glance the regexps are wrong: [ and ] are special characters defining sets/ranges of characters, . is any character. Also none of them has a catching group (parentheses). When compared as literals strings would also be different: parseR vs parser, extra [R, I, N]. How it's intended to work?

@MateuszKubuszok  the actual exMess would be longer and more detailed, but if you used exReg.firstFindIn(exMess) it returns the matched portion of the string.  Based on the incoming exMess it is supposed to match with either exReg(_) or the defined patterns and return the specified string.  If the exMess is longer than what is represented by the Regex pattern, will it not match?

Pattern matching with patten: Regexp (str match { case pattern(a, b, c) => ... }) matches only if the whole text is matched (unless it's .unanchored), and only if the number of capture groups matches the number of extracted values. And it's case sensitive by default. https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/util/matching/Regex.html case exReg.findFirstIn(exMess)  is not a legal extractor object.

case rex(x) => ... matches and extracts a capturing group.
For example:
val rex = "foo(..).".r
val foo = "foobar"
foo match { 
   case rex(x) => println(x) 
} 

will print "ba" ... but
val rex = "foo...r".r
foo match { 
   case rex(_) => println("yeah")
   case _ => println("nah")
}

will print nah because regex does not have a capturing group and the match is asking for one.
Your case exReg(_) =>  isn't working for the same reason: you are asking for a capturing group, but your regex doesn't have it.
Try removing the _: just case exReg() => ... should do it.
Alternatively, putting the entire thing in parentheses:
val exReg = "(parser[R,I,N].TokenException: at line 1)".r would make your syntax with _ work (I am not sure if parentheses in your snippet were intended to do this, they need to be inside the quotes, the way you have them, they are just redundant and do nothing).
Finally, if you wanted to use findFirstIn, you'd need to use it as a guard:
exMess match { 
   case x if exReg.findFirstIn(x).nonEmpty => ...
}


Thanks, your second suggestion with the "if" statement inside the match/case statement worked, but moving the parentheses inside the "" worked and provided a better solution

@user8675309 actually, an even better one was just getting rid of (_) ... not sure if you missed that one.
